# Rename genome FASTA files with part of sequence header

Tags: bash, filenames, fasta

I'd like to rename FASTA files with organism name (stored in the file) and the  identifier (part of the filename).

All files have the same format in filename and stored data, each file only have one FASTA header and corresponding sequence.

Original filename:

```
$ head GCF_000008205.1_ASM820v1_genomic.fna

>NC_007295.1 Mycoplasma hyopneumoniae J, complete genome
CCAAAATCAACTTTATTAAATGTGCTAAATAAAGTTGATAAAATGTTTGCAAAAACATTTTTGTTGTTTTAAACAAAACA
AATTGATTTAAAAATTATACTACAAAATTAAAGGAAAATTTATAAAATGCAAACAAATAAAAATAATTTAAAGGTTAGAA
CACAGCAAATTAGACAACAAATTGAAAATTTATTAAATGATCGAATGTTGTATAACAACTTTTTTAGCACAATTTATGTA
...
```

I'd like to rename only the filename, using the assembly identifier (GCF_000008205.1) in the filename, and the second and third words of the FASTA header (Mycoplasma hyopneumoniae):

```
Mycoplasma_hyopneumoniae_GCF_000008205.1.fna
```

I've tried this:

```
for fname in *.fna; do
mv -- "$fname" \
"$(awk 'NR==1{printf("%s_%s_%s\n",$2,$3,substr($1,2));exit}' "$fname")".fna
done
```

result:

```
Mycoplasma_hyopneumoniae_NC_007295.1.fna
```

But the result shows a code ahead of the name of the organism, instead of the identifier that interests me, which is in the name of the original file.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? The header is stored in the file? As the first line? What is the format of the header? Why is the `J,` and `complete genome` not part of the resulting filename?

Comment: Is there only one sequence per file, so you can assume there's only one FASTA header? Can you provide some additional examples of the headers?

Comment: FASTA header have repectively : sequence identifier, organism taxonomic genre, species name, sometimes subspecies name or strain, and completeness of the sequence (complete genome, scaffold or contig). Of sequence header it's needed the second and third word, which correspond for  organism taxonomic genre and species name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following idea works, but only if every single file is formatted like the one in your example.
In the directory that has all your files do the following:

```
for i in $(ls)
do
  name1=$(cat "$i" | grep \> | awk -v OFS='_' '{print $2,$3,_}')
  name2=$(basename "$i" | cut -d_ -f 1,2 | sed 's/$/.fna/g')
  mv "$i" "${name1}${name2}"
done
```

I suggest creating a backup folder first before trying it just in case you have some files formatted differently.